# php form validation returns mismatched error

Tags: php

I am new to php and this is my first post here, so new to writing post also.
I am using a script to vaidate a form input. Part of the script is as below:

```php
$data=$_POST;
print_r($data); 

if(($data['dm']="No") and (!empty($data['dmsince']))):
    $error=$error." dm mismatch N";  
endif;  

if(($data['dm']="Yes") and (empty($data['dmsince']))):
    $error=$error." dm mismatch Y";  
endif;

if ($error):
    print $error;
    $error="";   
    print $form;
else:
    print "OK";
```

I am accepting `$_POST['dm']` through select statement either as yes or no.

The problem that occurs is when the form is processed:

`$_POST['dm']='No'` and `$_POST['dmsince']` is blank.
I get error as `'dm mismatch Y'`.

`$_POST['dm']`=`Yes` and `$_POST['dmsince']='some valid date'`
I get error as `'dm mismatch N'`.

Logically in both these cases I should not get any error. It appears that it is entering one of the loops forcibly.
I have also tried with elseif with no result.
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `$data['dm']=="No"` and use `{}` brackets `if(2 > 1) { ... }else{ ... }`

Comment: you are using assignment instead of equality check.

Answer (score 3):

Update your conditionals to actually use conditional comparison operators (i.e. `==` or `===`).  Right now you are assigning $data['dm'] to equal "No" in the first conditional and "Yes" in the second.

You might also want to get in the habit of writing your comparisions like this:

```
if(true === $var)
if("Yes" === $var2)
```

With the item you are comparing the variable to on the left side.  In this manner if you accidentally did something like:

```
if(true=$var)
```

PHP would throw an error rather than a case like this

```
if($var=true)
```

Which would set $var = true and always evaluate the conditional as true.

It makes debugging your code a lot easier.

Comment: Thanx. I tried and my code now is:    if(("No"===$data['dm']) and (!empty($data['dmsince']))):
 $error=$error." dm mismatch N";
 endif;
 if(("Yes"===$data['dm']) and (empty($data['dmsince']))):
 $error=$error." dm mismatch Y";
 endif; But now I have exactly opposite situation. Though an error condition is fulfilled, it does not report error at all. It is not entering any of the loops.

Comment: @RatnamMani You may want to add a sample of var_dump($_POST) to your question to give more context.  Without knowing what sort of values you are posting which are causing unexpected results, it is hard to troubleshoot any farther.

Comment: I do not know how, but it got solved thus: Prior to checking consistency between $data['dm'] and $data['dmsince'], I was checking the empty string with if(!$data['dm']||$data['dm']=''): and capturing the error. I changed it to if(empty($data['dm']): and with that everything is fine. Thanks a lot.